# Override css style of an element given by id

Tags: html, css

I have an element in html as:

```
<label id="lb">Label1</label>
```

and in my corresponding css file:

```
#lb{
width:100px;
}
```

I need to override the style. Which is the best way?

Adding an inline style or can you suggest any other best way, like using a class from css file instead of inline styles? I would like to know the best practise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you cannot simply alter the original style rule - then either add the new style rule to the end of the existing style sheet or create a separate style sheet, import it into the page AFTER the first one and have the altered style rule in that - it will override the prior rule because it is located after it. It is best to avoid inline styling and you don't need to dynamically alter the orig rule with javascript - simply load the new style rule after the first one. Also best to avoid the use of !important to override style rules - there can be uninteded consequences from that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on a few things. But actually you add the same selector with style you want just a few lines later and it will work. As CSS says, it cascades from top to bottom. So if specificity is the same the last rule will be taken/added to the previous set rules. Also if you include entire CSS files.

```css
#lb {
   width:100px;
   background-color: green;
}

#lb {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<label id="lb">Label1</label>
```

If that is not doing the trick you should read about [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) which will explain why and when to use which selectors so the styles will apply.

That sayd also note that `inline-styles` are bad practice. So instead of adding inline styles you could also add a class name like:

```css
#lb {
   width:100px;
   background-color: green;
}

#lb {
    background-color: orange;
}

#lb.my-class {
    background-color: fuchsia;
}
```

```html
<label id="lb" class="my-class">Label1</label>
```

But now if you didn't read about specificity you will not understand why the next example is also `fuchsia` colored

```css
#lb.my-class {
    background-color: fuchsia;
}

#lb {
   width:100px;
   background-color: green;
}

#lb {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<label id="lb" class="my-class">Label1</label>
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to override the style in css.
Here is the first method

```
label#lb {
  background: red;
}

#lb {
  background: green;
}
```

The second method is using the `!important`.

```
#lb {
  background: red !important
}
#lb {
  background: green;
}
```

You can find the demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/zcyep6k1/ 
Background color is used for demonstration.

**Update:**
Caramba's method is better if you just want to override the style right after original rule.

Answer (score 2):

There are few ways to overwrite, I believe the below method is the best solution.

present code

```
#lb{
width:100px;
}
```

from first option to last option

**1. Refer to a parent element**

`parentElement #lb{
    width:100px;
    }`

note: Its best to go on referring the parent to couple of levels, example: div div div #lb.
until you do not complicate the nesting.

**2. refer the body element**

`body #lb{
    width:100px;
    }`

**3. use important for the element directly**

`#lb{
        width:100px !important;
        }`

**4. use important with referring to parent element directly**

`parentElement  #lb{
    width:100px !important;
    }`

**5. use important with referring to body element** 
`body #lb{
    width:100px !important;
    }`

Try to avoid using inline styling at all cost, it is not good practice and you should only use inline when ur dealing with JavaScript.  Some may say, we can use for small solutions, but my understanding is that in the long run, it could really trouble you. I recommend to avoid using inline styling as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can always override it with at least the **same priority CSS** within a sequence of css class/id declaration such as:

HTML:

```
<label id="lb">Label1</label>
```

CSS:

```
#lb{
width:100px;
}

#lb{
width:200px;     //this will override 100px
}
```

**Best Practice:**

1. dont use ID for styling, use classes instead
2. If you are using external library such as Bootstrap, dont change their code, just copy some part of the one you want to override to new file, then change in new file and load library first then the override css.

Answer (score 0):

Use the !important tag. Unless you know the sequence when the browser loads the file.

```
#lb{
 width:100px !important;
}
```

When you use !important, your browser will know "THIS IS IMPORTANT!"